# SQL adding result of 2 count querys

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wish to run the same query on 2 tables and get a combined result. The internal sub-query returns 2 strings and I want to count how many occurances of those strings exist in the 2 tables. The query below gives me the result for each table separately, but how can I combine this into a single query or add the numerical result of each in SQL Server? Thanks

```
select count(1)
from Team
where Team.TeamName IN (select Data FROM CSVTest_Match WHERE Header in ('Home Team', 'Away Team'))

select count(1)
from TeamAlias
where TeamAlias.TeamName  IN (select Data FROM CSVTest_Match WHERE Header in ('Home Team', 'Away Team'));
```

Comment: If the value is present both on team and also teamalias do you want it counted once or twice?

Comment: You should use `inner join` instead of `IN (SELECT` (Performance improved)

Comment: Brian, the strings should never be repeated in both tables. However, your code below is not working for me. I get: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near ';'. Expecting AS, ID or QUOTED_ID. The other suggested solution gives me the same problem :os

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(
    select 1
    from Team
    where Team.TeamName IN (select Data FROM CSVTest_Match WHERE Header in ('Home Team', 'Away Team'))
    UNION ALL
    select 1
    from TeamAlias
    where TeamAlias.TeamName  IN (select Data FROM CSVTest_Match WHERE Header in ('Home Team', 'Away Team'))
) t
```

Comment: You got there just before me.  I had the same answer.  +1.

Comment: Is that 't' at the very end a typo? With it I get error: No column name was specified for column 1 of 't'. Without it I get:  Incorrect syntax near end of file. Expecting AS, ID or QUOTED_ID

Comment: No it is no typo. Typo is in another place. You must add and alias to result (after 1), or change `t` to `t(cnt)`.

Comment: Thanks Hamlet. That works great with (cnt) on the end. Maybe you want to edit the solution and I will mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the counts overlapping (see my comment):

```
select sum(num_recs)
  from (select count(*) as num_recs
          from team t
          join CSVTest_Match c
            on t.teamname = c.data
         where c.header in ('Home Team', 'Away Team')
        union all
        select count(*) as num_recs
          from teamalias t
          join CSVTest_Match c
            on t.teamname = c.data
         where c.header in ('Home Team', 'Away Team')) X;
```

Comment: This is not working for me. I get: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12 Incorrect syntax near ';'. Expecting AS, ID or QUOTED_ID.

Comment: @SteveW It might just want you to give an alias for the inline view (I think that is sql server specific). I put an X after it if you want to retry.